# Is it possible to repurpose a Trend Micro IGSA (Cisco 1113) appliance server?

Tags: boot, bios, bootloader, appliance

I have a practially unused Trend Micro IGSA appliance without any valid license. It's not hyper fast or anything but it is a x86 box with the same motherboard as in a Cisco 1113 and sports a user-replacable AMIBIOS chip. Most importantly: it is *red*.

[Red IGSA appliance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai8hD.jpg)

Out of the box, no external peripherals are supported, USB ports are disabled. Only 3x 10/100/1000 LAN and a serial com port. It boots from 512MB CF and also has a 80GB SATA HDD. 
The question is: Can I put an OS of my liking on it? What would I have to do?

Comment: Have you tried installing Linux to it?  You would need to remove the hdd, install it on a system that does support USB/optical disk drive and go from there.  Its unlikely Windows would run on the machine so don't even try.

Comment: I had to read your comment 3 times to fully get what you mean. I think I need a CF reader first and whats on the disk. Thanks!

Comment: Update - the IGSA runs a watchdog in the bios which I was unable to circumvent so I couldn't boot anything else on it.